# Extract date from String column in sql

Tags: sql, string, date

I have a column as **current_data** and it has data which is of type **string** and data as {"settlement_date":"2018-07-21"}. 
My question is that for each trade the settlement date will be diffrent and i want to extract the date i.e **2018-07-21** from the column **current_data** for each trade. I tried using select to_char(date_trunc(d.current_data,'YYYY-MM-DD')) as "Current_date" also i have tried the trim fuction but it does not work

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? This seems like JSON format to me. Are you sure internally it's stored as string (text)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `JSON` data. Since you're saying it's a text column internally you could use `substring` function to cut only the data you're looking for.

```
select substring(current_data from 21 for 10) from yourtable
```

You start taking the substring from 21 character and specify that it's length will be the next 10 characters.

With your sample data the result would be

```
db=# select substring('{"settlement_date":"2018-07-21"}' from 21 for 10);
 substring
------------
 2018-07-21
```

Beware though that this solution relies on length of the string and is designed for static input where the extracted substring is always within the same position.

Comment: I have tried that got error @Kamil G. Function date_trunc(unknown, varchar) does not exist, or permission is denied for date_trunc(unknown, varchar)

Comment: There is no `date_trunc` function in my answer. Are you sure you've tried my solution and not yours?

Comment: @TAJINDERSINGH this is unclear to me. Update your answer with all relevant information so that people could provide help.

Comment: when I ran query :
select 
d.current_data ,
(select substring('current_data' from 21 for 10)) as modified_data
from DAILY_AMENDED_TRADE_REPORT d
INNER JOIN TRADE_REPORT t 
ON d.trade_id=t.trade_id
and d.source_system=t.source_system where business_date='2018-06-01'

Answer i got is 
current_data:{"settlement_date":"2018-06-20"} and modified_data is empty
modified_data

Comment: @TAJINDERSINGH you need to remove apostrophes around `current_data`. It's a column reference, so it shouldn't be a string. Rephrase your query at start to: `select d.current_data, substring(d.current_data from 21 for 10) as modified_data from ...` You also don't need another select in there (I removed it)